# Regex - Adding a new line and word after every line beginning with certain phrase

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm currently writing a program in java, and I have 100s of different lines of code beginning with

```
Bw.write
```

How can I make it so after every line beginning with Bw.write, I can insert a new line under it with `BufferedWriter.newLine();`

Thanks in advance

EDIT: Sorry for the confusion

For example I need

```
Bw.write 12345
Bw.write 98765
```

to become

```
Bw.write 12345
BufferedWriter.newLine();
Bw.write 98765
BufferedWriter.newLine();
```

Comment: Check [HERE](https://regex101.com/r/C43EwF/1). Get the code help from [HERE](https://regex101.com/r/C43EwF/1/codegen?language=java)

Comment: this is close, but I have stuff written after the "Bw.write"s that i need to stay on the same line as Bw.write

Comment: I have updated my answer below. Just add the `.*` in the find expression

Comment: Oh i see, thanks for the help, that works great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `Bw\.write.*` with `$0\r\nBufferedWriter\.newLine()`

[Click for DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/C43EwF/3)

**Before Replace:**

[image]

**After Replace All:**

[image]

Comment: I phrased the question badly, I edited the OP and gave an example